# Regarding webservice created using PHP_soap

Tags: php

I have developed webservice using php_soap. i am call the webservice and get perfect data. But my client say it is not working with .net. How can i test that server is correct or not??

Answer (score 0):

Test from your .NET client, look at the request/response and debug what your web service does with that request.

Might help to use for instance XDEBUG to actually run your web service in an IDE, set breakpoints etc.